# How can we take advantage of the Bluetooth Scanning / Location Improvement programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, locationmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth-lowenergy

Since Android Marshmallow we can activate Bluetooth Scanning for location improvements. This feature scans for BLE device in the background even if Bluetooth is NOT activated. Is there a way we can get notified that there was a BLE Device found (UUID,MAYOR,MINOR), BroadcastReceiver maybe ?

I already raised an Enhancement request [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199109&q=BLE&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) but I haven't heard from them.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do is possible without being a system app.

Per the description on the device settings: "...**allowing system services**..."

[image: Scanning]

---

If you were to write a system service to gather the scan callbacks, you would do so by getting a handle on a `BluetoothAdapter#LeScanCallback`, like so:

```
@Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

        if( device == null ) {
             // perform work here
        }

        // example
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

---

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: What I was thinking was more like listening to a Broadcast like we do for the WIFI State change , for example.